# Image Boundary Finding and Filling

Tags: numpy, scipy, scikit-image

I have a single-band binary image (consisting of only 0 and 1 pixel values) as shown in the figure below.

I have to convert all the black pixels inside the outer white boundaries into whites.
The black pixels outside the outer white boundaries should remain black.

How would you do it?

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you could also include an image describing what parts of the image should be filled and not, i.e define what is inside and outside.

Comment: A schematic figure done in paint would be sufficient, it does not need to be an exact representation of the solution. The definition of white polygon in the figure could be ambiguous, which @Stefan van der Walt discovered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code below yields the following result:

[image]

I've commented the code inline to explain what I've done.

```py
from skimage import io, img_as_bool, measure, morphology
from scipy import ndimage

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Read the image, convert the values to True or False;
# discard all but the red channel (since it's a black and
# white image, they're all the same)
image = img_as_bool(io.imread('borders.png'))[..., 0]

# Compute connected regions in the image; we're going to use this
# to find centroids for our watershed segmentation
labels = measure.label(image)
regions = measure.regionprops(labels)

# Marker locations for the watershed segmentation; we choose these to
# be the centroids of the different connected regions in the image
markers = np.array([r.centroid for r in regions]).astype(np.uint16)
marker_image = np.zeros_like(image, dtype=np.int64)
marker_image[markers[:, 0], markers[:, 1]]  = np.arange(len(markers)) + 1

# Compute the distance map, which provides a "landscape" for our watershed
# segmentation
distance_map = ndimage.distance_transform_edt(1 - image)

# Compute the watershed segmentation; it will over-segment the image
filled = morphology.watershed(1 - distance_map, markers=marker_image)

# In the over-segmented image, combine touching regions
filled_connected = measure.label(filled != 1, background=0) + 1

# In this optional step, filter out all regions that are < 25% the size
# of the mean region area found
filled_regions = measure.regionprops(filled_connected)
mean_area = np.mean([r.area for r in filled_regions])
filled_filtered = filled_connected.copy()
for r in filled_regions:
    if r.area < 0.25 * mean_area:
        coords = np.array(r.coords).astype(int)
        filled_filtered[coords[:, 0], coords[:, 1]] = 0

# And display!
f, (ax0, ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 3)
ax0.imshow(image, cmap='gray')
ax1.imshow(filled_filtered, cmap='spectral')
ax2.imshow(distance_map, cmap='gray')
plt.savefig('/tmp/labeled_filled_regions.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

Comment: I'm afraid I am now in the same position as @hakanc.  I'd need to see an example of what you want the output to be.