# Filling objects based on the boundaries

Tags: numpy, scipy, contour, scikit-image, boundary

I would like to fill the objects based on their boundaries. I did found something similar has been done already as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29573126/image-boundary-finding-and-filling). But with this I am not able to fill more than one object. For example, my image is

[image]

and the output with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29573126/image-boundary-finding-and-filling) code is

[image]

As you can see, it can fill only one object and not the top right object. Do you have some suggestions? What could be wrong? what can I try?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you might want to [label connected components](https://scipy-lectures.org/packages/scikit-image/auto_examples/plot_labels.html)